# Laravel in controller return new collection of results from a foreach loop through records

Tags: eloquent, laravel-6

This seems like it should be obvious, but everything I find relates to returning a collection extracted from records, rather then returning a collection of new results derived from calculations on the records.

For instance, say I have records of property in my database. I can extract a collection of a subset (or the entire set) of the records. But I want to loop through this collection, calculate new values for each line item, (like marketValue-debt=netValue) and return a new collection of just those results to my view. I'm trying to keep my (much more complicated than this example) calculation in my controller and out of my view, but I'm not getting the way to stuff new values into a new collection of results for return to display in the view.

I could derive my results and stuff them into an array, but how do I pass this as a new collection for looping through in my view to show those results? Seems like there should be an Eloquent way to do this.

My project is in Laravel 6 running on Apache/Laragon, PHP 7 with MariaDb

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Comment: What you looking for is `$collection->transform(someCallback() {})` that will change the items within the collection. For more https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-transform

Comment: No, I'm trying to create a new collection with new "fields" and values to then pass to the view from the controller, not modify the collection pulled from the database.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-transform). Hope it will be of some help.

If you want a new collection, use the `map` method.

```
$new_collection = $old_collection->map(function ($item) {
    return $item->marketValue - $item->debtValue;
});
```